# VBA GetKeyboardState usage - cant get my head round it

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard, state

I'm struggling to understand how the get keyboard state works. The answer on my last question is so great, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

[Trying to capture key press while sub running ( for snake game ) VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725598/trying-to-capture-key-press-while-sub-running-for-snake-game-vba)

I have declared the function ( and used PTRSAFE ) but I cannot see how the code below it is used. I have tried making a sub but I don't understand is supposed to be happening, so can someone explain it to me?

I can see it checks from 0 to 255 but don't see how it relates to the function to get the state?

```
Public Declare Function GetKeyboardState Lib "user32" Alias "GetKeyboardState" (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long

dim keybrdbuff(255) as byte

For x = 0 to 255
    If 0<>keybrdbuff(x) then Exit Sub
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of the 256 virtual keys are pressed then it is not 0. If not 0 then it exits the sub, aborting the rest of your moves. Windows will then send the key to the window in a normal way and your program will treat it normally.

You have to run the for loop whereever you may want to abort the rest ofthe moves.

**GetKeyboardState Function**

---

The GetKeyboardState function copies the status of the 256 virtual keys to the specified buffer.

Syntax

```
BOOL GetKeyboardState(          PBYTE lpKeyState
);
```

**Parameters**

lpKeyState
[in] Pointer to the 256-byte array that receives the status data for each virtual key. 
Return Value

If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.

If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Remarks

An application can call this function to retrieve the current status of all the virtual keys. The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue. The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue, nor does it change as keyboard messages are posted to or retrieved from message queues of other threads. (Exception: Threads that are connected through AttachThreadInput share the same keyboard state.)

When the function returns, each member of the array pointed to by the lpKeyState parameter contains status data for a virtual key. If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up. If the key is a toggle key, for example CAPS LOCK, then the low-order bit is 1 when the key is toggled and is 0 if the key is untoggled. The low-order bit is meaningless for non-toggle keys. A toggle key is said to be toggled when it is turned on. A toggle key's indicator light (if any) on the keyboard will be on when the key is toggled, and off when the key is untoggled.

To retrieve status information for an individual key, use the GetKeyState function. To retrieve the current state for an individual key regardless of whether the corresponding keyboard message has been retrieved from the message queue, use the GetAsyncKeyState function.

An application can use the virtual-key code constants VK_SHIFT, VK_CONTROL and VK_MENU as indices into the array pointed to by lpKeyState. This gives the status of the SHIFT, CTRL, or ALT keys without distinguishing between left and right. An application can also use the following virtual-key code constants as indices to distinguish between the left and right instances of those keys:

```
VK_LSHIFT 
VK_RSHIFT 
VK_LCONTROL 
VK_RCONTROL 
VK_LMENU 
VK_RMENU
```

These left- and right-distinguishing constants are available to an application only through the GetKeyboardState, SetKeyboardState, GetAsyncKeyState, GetKeyState, and MapVirtualKey functions.