# Getkeystate not returning the correct value?

Tags: excel, vba

Guys really stuck getting my head round the getkeyboardstate() function and the getkeystate() function

I want to tell if the arrow keys are being pressed and if they are then exit sub.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long
```

Im using the above and then using the following in a sub;

```
GetKeyState(44)
```

Im looking to see if printscreen is pressed but it doesn't seem to ever return a 0

What am i doing wrong? does anyone know?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23727251/3198973

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to be your problem.

If I run this:

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Sub luxation()
For j = 1 To 300
    For i = 1 To 100000
        If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyA)) Then
            MsgBox "Got an a"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyPrint)) Then
            MsgBox "Got PrintScreen"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeySnapshot)) Then
            MsgBox "Got snap"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
Next j
MsgBox "Failed"
End Sub
```

On my elderly Dell, it will loop for about 30 seconds if I touch no keys.

If I touch the <kbd>A</kbd> key I get the appropriate message.

If I touch the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> key I get the **snap** message and not the **PrintScreen** message.

So at least on my Dell, I need to use *vbKeySnapshot* to trap the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks i managed to get it to work!! But It didn't accomplish what i wanted it to do!! ah well back to the drawing board!